# Laravel - allow to download files from a folder in blade view

Tags: arrays, laravel, download, laravel-blade

I'm stuck somewhere in the middle and I can't go on. Have folder, in folder files. In blade.view wants them download via link.

```
$fileNameGlob = glob($directory."*.*", GLOB_BRACE);
```

`dd($fileNameGlob)` return array

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "/var/www/html/domain/storage/app/apiFiles/611106/extract/1.png"
  1 => "/var/www/html/domain/storage/app/apiFiles/611106/extract/2.png"
  2 => "/var/www/html/domain/storage/app/apiFiles/611106/extract/3.jpg"
  ]
```

when i try `return response()->download($fileNameGlob)` have problem with `array`. If i have file path how continue to download file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to provide one link to download all files? Then you should zip the files beforehand and then deliver the zipfile path.
You could also use:

```
return response->download('apiFiles/611106/extract/1.png');                 
return response()->download('apiFiles/611106/extract/1.png', $name, $headers);
```

But this would not work for the array, but for the single elements, so you should provide something like $fileNameGlob[i].

Comment: my goal is download link in table in blade view for each file from directory

Comment: So you need a route that takes a filename as parameter and use an anchor <a> to trigger the download?

Comment: is another way, or only with route?

Comment: Yes, there is another way. The images can be made publicly available if you put them in the public directory or better symlink storage/app/public which you can do via php artisan storage:link (see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: I think "better" is relative... but if you work inside storage/, you can use all the helper functions laravel provides. (See the link from my last comment)